# Remove table entry if BOTH foreign keys were deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, onupdate

I have a table with 2 foreign keys that reference the same field within another table. I know how to define the foreign key constraint to remove my table entry if at least one of the two foreign keys become deleted. But instead I want to keep the table entry if at least one of the foreign keys still exist?

```
CREATE TABLE PrivateMessages
  ...
  INDEX(FromEmail, ToEmail),
  FOREIGN KEY(FromEmail, ToEmail) 
    REFERENCES Users(Email, Email) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ...
```

The table stores messages between two users. I want to delete messages if both users don't exist any longer, only. Maybe, is there a better approach to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... I want to keep the table entry if at least one of the foreign keys still exist*
>
> *I want to delete messages if both users don't exist any longer, only.*

It can't be achieved just by defining a constraint.

Possible procedure:

1. Define a `marked_for_delete bit not null default 0` column feature.
2. Whenever you want to delete a user, mark it for deletion, by an
   *update* call.
3. Define either a *before* or an *after* type of *delete trigger* on
   the table.
4. In the trigger body, check if the combo of `fromEmail` and `toEmail`
   are marked for deletion, then execute a `delete` statement on the
   parent table and the child combo will be deleted as your required
   condition matched.